# the following is giving an error, please tell what is wrong with it

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
main( )
{ int num[ ] = {24, 34, 12, 44, 56, 17};
 dislpay(&num[0],6); 
}
display ( int *j, int n ) 
{
int i ;
for ( i = 0 ; i <= n - 1 ; i++ )
 { 
  printf ( "\nelement = %d", *j ) ; 
  j++ ; /* increment pointer to point to next element */ 
    }
}
```

The language is c, windows vista using visual c++ 2005 express.

Comment: Adding details like what the error message is, would help with us answering your questions. Other details, like what language this is (it appears to be c), what platform (linux, windows etc...) would also be handy.

Comment: Where are the return types of `main()` and `display()`? Either provide a declaration of `display()` above `main()` or move the entire definition above `main()`

Comment: You could try spelling `display` correctly when you call it.

Comment: Looks like homework to me, mister!

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? I had intentionally made my post community wiki.

Comment: Why do we even bother answering this kind of questions?

Answer (score 2):

The correct code should be something like :

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 void display(int*, int); //declaration of your function 

 int main( ) //return type of main should be int
 {
      int num[ ] = {24, 34, 12, 44, 56, 17};
      display(&num[0],6);  //Correct the spelling mistake
 }
 void display ( int *j, int n ) //specify a return type
 {
     int i ;
     for ( i = 0 ; i <= n - 1 ; i++ )
     { 
            printf ( "\nelement = %d", j[i] ) ; 

     }
 }
```

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav - you marked this as community wiki, so any votes will not effect your rep.

Comment: If your gonna have non-void return in main( ) you should at least `return 0;` . I didn't down vote you though, looks like proper solution.

Comment: For being too right. ;)  Whether this is homework or learning C, aja will learn more effectively if we don't do it for him.

Comment: @Oded : I know that but I was surprised to see my answer getting a downvote even though it is perfectly correct.

Comment: @wfoster : Nopes! In C99, explicit `return 0;` is optional.

Comment: @dublev : Thats why I intentionally made my post community wiki because I did not want any reputation point for this answer. :-)

Comment: @Prasoon: Ooops, just let my rookie-status be known :)

Comment: Random downvotes happen all the time, don't take them to heart. Sometimes you will get an answer (which you may or may not agree with), sometimes you won't even get that.

Comment: &num[0] is the same as num, therefore i think more flexible is: display(num,sizeof num/sizeof*num);

Answer (score 0):

Typo line 4, dislpay -> display?

Comment: ...I'm just saying, given the info by the poster this is the best I could give.

Comment: The lack of return types could be a problem too.

Comment: Oh, this *does* look like homework!  And the only other post he has on SO is homework too!  KHAAAAAAN!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting an error, besides your typo, is that in C, you cannot refer to a variable or function before its declaration. Thus you can fix your code by either moving the display function to before main, or as Prasoon did, add a declaration above main.

Technically you can leave out return types as C assumes int (at least ANSI C89 does), but it's not a good idea.  It's good practice to always specify return type to improve readability and avoid tricky type-mismatch bugs (especially since C does a lot of implicit casting).